# Convert "number stored as text" in excel to general format WITHOUT changing current value/content

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i Have many cells with some numbers stored as text like this one: `48820912927088000170550010004765131620601995`

But when i try to convert it to number it converts to `4,8820912927088E+43` and no matter what i do, tried changing every format and it don't output as the original value.

```
Sub convert ()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rConst As Range

    ' pick an unused cell
    Set rConst = Cells(1, 4)
    rConst = 1

    Set rng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rng.NumberFormat = "General"
    rConst.Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply

    rConst.Clear
End Sub
```

I know there's a lot of answers similar of that, but i didn't find no one that matches with my issue?

Someone can help?

Thank you

Comment: Excel only stores 15 significant digits.  You will need to set the cells as text and store the number as such.  So basically you need to leave them stored as text if you want to see all the digits.

Comment: In addition to what @ScottCraner wrote, there are add-ins available that can perform mathematical calculations on long numbers stored as text.

Comment: There's a way in vba without add-ins to take all the written characteres and replace it in `number` or `general format` ?

Comment: Depending on the actual calculation you can implement loops to run over each character from end of the string to the first one. But we lack details of what you are actually trying.

Comment: Internally, excel uses Variant/double to store numbers.  Consequently, any format will be limited by the size of the number that can be stored by a Double.  The largest positive integer that can be stored in a Double without using the exponent is 2^53 (9,007,199,254,740,992) so you can see that numbers like 48820912927088000170550010004765131620601995 cannot be represented by a double without loss of precision.  If you need to do math using numbers such as 48820912927088000170550010004765131620601995 it will require you to write code that uses the Microsoft .Net BigInt library.

Comment: @freeflow can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following c# code is an example of how to get access to the BigInteger object is the Net Systen.Numerics.

The Class

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Numerics;

namespace BigStuff
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IBigNum))]
    public class BigNum : IBigNum
    {
        public string Add(string ipVar1, string ipVar2)
        {
            BigInteger myVar1 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1);
            BigInteger myVar2 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar2);
            return BigInteger.Add(myVar1, myVar2).ToString();
        }

        public string Sub(string ipVar1, string ipVar2)
        {
            BigInteger myVar1 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1);
            BigInteger myVar2 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar2);
            return BigInteger.Subtract(myVar1, myVar2).ToString();
        }

        public string Mul(string ipVar1, string ipVar2)
        {
            BigInteger myVar1 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1);
            BigInteger myVar2 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar2);
            return BigInteger.Multiply(myVar1, myVar2).ToString();
        }

        public string Div(string ipVar1, string ipVar2)
        {
            BigInteger myVar1 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1);
            BigInteger myVar2 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar2);
            return BigInteger.Divide(myVar1, myVar2).ToString();
        }

        public string Mod(string ipVar1, string ipVar2)
        {
            BigInteger myVar1 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1);
            BigInteger myVar2 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar2);
            return BigInteger.Remainder(myVar1, myVar2).ToString();
        }

        public string[] DivRem(string ipVar1, string ipVar2)
        {
            BigInteger myVar1 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1);
            BigInteger myVar2 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar2);
            BigInteger myMod = 0;
            BigInteger myDiv = BigInteger.DivRem(myVar1, myVar2, out myMod);
            return new string[] { myDiv.ToString(), myMod.ToString() };
        }

        public string Neg(string ipVar1)
        {
            return BigInteger.Negate(BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1)).ToString();
        }

        public string Abs(string ipVar1)
        {
            return BigInteger.Abs(BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1)).ToString();
        }

        public int Compare(string ipVar1, string ipVar2)
        {
            BigInteger myVar1 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1);
            BigInteger myVar2 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar2);
            return BigInteger.Compare(myVar1, myVar2);
        }

        public dynamic Pow(string ipVar1, int ipVar2)
        {
            BigInteger myVar1 = BigInteger.Parse(ipVar1);

            return (dynamic)BigInteger.Pow(myVar1, ipVar2).ToString();
        }


    }
}
```

The interface needed for Com.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BigStuff
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IBigNum
    {
        string Add(string ipVar1, string ipVar2);


        string Sub(string ipVar1, string ipVar2);

        string Mul(string ipVar1, string ipVar2);

        string Div(string ipVar1, string ipVar2);

        string Mod(string ipVar1, string ipVar2);

        string[] DivRem(string ipVar1, string ipVar2);

        string Neg(string ipVar1);

        string Abs(string ipVar1);

        int Compare(string ipVar1, string ipVar2);

        dynamic Pow(string ipVar1, int ipVar2);
    }
}
```

The code above was compiled to a c# windows library using Framework 4.8.1.
The code above needs a reference to "System.Numerics" added.

After compiling the code, in VBA your need to add a reference to the BigStuff.tlb which will be in the BigStuff.bin.Debug folder of the c# project directory.

In VBA you can now do something like

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim myInt As BigStuff.BigNum
    Set myInt = New BigNum
    Debug.Print myInt.Add("48820912927088000170550010004765131620601995", "2")
    
    Dim myNum As String
    myNum = myInt.Mul("9007199254740992", "4096")
    Debug.Print myNum
    
End Sub
```

which gives the output

48820912927088000170550010004765131620601997
36893488147419103232

The example is not complete and  hasn't been tested to any extent at all, but the example will serve as a useful pointer if you wish to develop your own code.

To compile the c# example above you will at least need to install Visual Studio Community.

Comment: Thank you! I can't do by this way now, but it may help someone else